# Color scaling with php

Tags: php, css, colors

I know there are similar topics but I couldn't figure out how to swap it.

I need to change color from RED to GREEN depending on number (percent 1 - 100)

What I used so far was

```
    $R=round((255*$percent)/100);
    $G=round((255*(100-$percent))/100); 
    $pcol= '<strong style="color: rgb('.$R.','.$G.',0)">'.$nxm['s']['kom'].'</strong>';
```

The problem is that this one uses red for MAX and green for MIN, I wanna switch it to the opposite. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: is color depended on percent like if percent is less than text will display in RED color , if percent increase than text will be GREEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some workaround:

You can try get computing for the percentage of GREEN, and for the RED, just subtract green's value from 255.
I made a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/unuxdon5/1/) using a similar approach just to show how it works.

**IN PHP:**

```
$G=round(255*$percent/100);
$R=255-$G; 
$pcol= '<strong style="color: rgb('.$R.','.$G.',0)">'.$nxm['s']['kom'].'</strong>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch `$R` and `$G` in your `$pcol`:

```
$R=round((255*$percent)/100);
$G=round((255*(100-$percent))/100); 
$pcol= '<strong style="color: rgb('.$G.','.$R.',0)">'.$nxm['s']['kom'].'</strong>';
```

Comment: Nope, I tried it already in that case it starts from 'dark green' and ends up to some kind of 'lime'..